# SQL datareader field name out of range

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem that I need some help with. I have the following query:

```
        SqlCommand randCode = new SqlCommand("(SELECT COUNT(student_ID) FROM COMPLETED)", conn);
        SqlDataReader randCodeR;
        connectie.Open();
        randCodeR = randCode.ExecuteReader();

        int count = randCodeR.GetOrdinal("student_ID");
```

There are 500 students in COMPLETED and the randCodeR has 1 field that has the value of 500. Now, I want that value into the count variable but when I try the code above it says student_ID in randCodeR.GetOrdinal("student_ID") is out of range. Why does it not see student_ID in the datareader and how do I get the value out of it? Thanks.

Microsft SQL server 2012

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
int count = randCodeR.GetOrdinal("student_ID");
```

to

```
int count = (int)randCode.ExecuteScalar();
```

So [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `SqldataReader.GetOrdinal` which returns in the index of the column in the result set. You don't need the reader at all.

Comment: Hey, I get the following error: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteScalar' and no extension method 'ExecuteScalar' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ?
                                                                     I have using System.Data.SqlClient; included.

Comment: @NiekJonkman: My fault, edited my answer. You have to use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @NiekJonkman: Remember to accept the best answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Because `student_ID` does not exists. Specifying an alias on the calculated column will remove the error.

```
string _sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(student_ID) student_ID FROM COMPLETED";
SqlCommand randCode = new SqlCommand(_sqlQuery, conn);
```